Using line length as part of a TikZ style calculation
Because I am going to make a lot of figures where the same spring is in different states of compression or extension, I spent some time developing a dynamic style for springs.
This style takes 4 arguments:

The number of spring segments
The length of the line to be decorated as a spring
The length of the straight lines at the start and end of the spring
The width of the spring

From the first three arguments, the style calculates the length of each spring segment to fit the desired number of spring segments. By keeping the number of spring segments constant and changing the length of the line, I can draw compressed and extended springs.
Here is my MWE code:
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
    spring/.code n args={4}{  % no. of coils, spring length, pre/post length, amplitude
        \pgfmathparse{(#2 - 2*#3) / #1}   % Calculate segment length
        \pgfkeysalso{
            decoration={
                zigzag,   % "coil" decoration's segment length is too imprecise
                segment length = \pgfmathresult cm,
                pre length = #3 cm,
                post length = #3 cm,
                amplitude = #4 cm},
           decorate
        }
    }
}

\draw[spring={10}{3}{0.5}{0.2}] (0, 0) -- ++(3,0);
\draw[spring={10}{4}{0.5}{0.2}] (0,-1) -- ++(4,0);
\draw[spring={10}{5}{0.5}{0.2}] (0,-2) -- ++(5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


While this seems to work well, having the line length as a style argument seems unnecessary, and it's a little annoying to have to calculate it myself every time, especially if the spring is not aligned with the x or y axes. Is there any information on the line length available to the style, so that I could use that information rather than specifying it manually? (I have already experimented a little with the \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength macro, but with no luck.)
A second issue, which is not my main question, is that I had use the zigzag decoration
instead of the coil decoration because coil doesn't seem to stick exactly to the segment length that is specified for the decoration. The actual coil segment length was often a little longer than I specified, so that fewer coil segments were used and the post length was extended slightly. (If we switch zigzag to coil in the MWE, the upper and middle coils get 9 segments instead of 10, and a slightly longer straight line at the end.) Is it possible to make the coil decoration use the specified segment length exactly?

maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720952/36296 might be helpful

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Unfortunately, that solution still requires an external calculation. (It requires the decoration segment length to be calculated, while my original solution requires the line length.)


I imagine that you would like to use coil to represent the springs in your drawings; consequently I'm considering only the decoration coil in the sequel.
I defined a decoration spring that takes four arguments: the number of coils, the amplitude, the pre-post distance, and the color.
Some comments.
From the manual (the paragraph Decoration coil): To understand how this works, imagine a three dimensional spring. The spring’s axis points along the path toward the target. Then, we “view” the spring from a certain angle. If we look “straight from the side” we will see a perfect sine curve, if we look “more from the front” we will see a coil.  It has three parameters: segment length, amplitude, and aspect.
In the next image, the drawings use two aspects (.2 and .5) and various amplitudes.  The segment length parameter (the wave length) is the same, pi/2.

Three things must be noticed:

The main interval [0, pi] (the lenght of a wave) is marked by the white point.

When the aspect is 0.5 and the amplitude 2, the curve (in red) is not drawn on the entire main interval.

The spring ends always with the first upward curl of the last wave.


So, to be able to obtain the spring decoration, we need to control the length of the upward curl of a wave.  With some mathematical computations, I have the formula when the aspect is 0.5: d = (wave length)/2 + (aplitude).
In the next drawing, the filled intersection points represent the end of the upward curl.  When the aspect is 0.2, they don't seem to be correct (there is an error that can be seen on the red point especially).  The formula I was trying is
d = (wave length)/2 + 2*(aplitude)*sin((aspect)*60).

Coming back to apsect=.5, when the formula seems to hold true, using this distance, we can compute the segment length of the coil decoration from the length of the entire spring and the number of coils:
(segment length) = ((spring length - (amplitude)) / ((nr of coils) - 1/2).
The code (first image)
\documentclass[border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for show control points

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  spring/.style n args={4}{% nb of coils, ampl, pre/post length, color
    decoration={%
      show path construction,
      lineto code={
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (FSpr);
        \path (\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (LSpr);
        \tikzmath{%
          coordinate \v, \w;
          \v = ($(LSpr) - (FSpr)$);
          real \a, \d, \wl;
          \a = {atan2(\vy, \vx)};
          {%
            \draw[#4] (FSpr) -- ++(\a: #3) coordinate (ASpr);
            \draw[#4] (LSpr) -- ++(\a +180: #3) coordinate (BSpr);
          };
          \w = ($(BSpr) - (ASpr)$);
          \d = {veclen(\wx, \wy)*1pt/1cm}; % in centimeters
          \wl = {(\d -#2)/(#1 -1/2) -.001};  
        }
        \draw[decorate, decoration={%
          coil,
          segment length=\wl cm,
          amplitude=#2 cm,
          aspect=.5
        }, #4] (ASpr) -- (BSpr);
      },
    },
    decorate
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[gray, very thin, opacity=.3] (0, -5) grid (10, 2);
  
  \draw[spring={6}{.6}{.2}{black}] (0, 0) --++(15: 6);
  \draw[spring={6}{.6}{.2}{red!20!black}] (-75: 1.5) --++(15: 7);
  \draw[spring={6}{.6}{.2}{red!40!black}] (-75: 3) --++(15: 8);
  \draw[spring={6}{.6}{.2}{red!60!black}] (-75: 4.5) --++(15: 9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The code (third image)
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for show control points

\begin{document}
\tikzmath{%
  real \cpim \hpi;
  \cpi = 3.14159;
  \hpi = \cpi/3;
}
\tikzset{%
  test/.style 2 args={%  ampl, aspect, 
    decorate, decoration={coil,
      segment length=\cpi cm,
      amplitude=#1 cm,
      aspect=#2
    }
  }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \draw[gray, very thin, opacity=.5] (0, -2) grid (6.3, 2);
    
    \draw[test={.5}{.2}] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[] ({\cpi/2 +2*.5*sin(.2*60)}, 0) circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[test={1}{.2}, blue] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[blue] ({\cpi/2 +2*1*sin(.2*60)}, 0) circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[test={2}{.2}, red] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[red] ({\cpi/2 +2*2*sin(.2*60)}, 0) circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[fill=white] (\cpi, 0) circle (1.5pt);   

    \path (4, -1.5) node[right] {asp=0.2}; 
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
    \draw[gray, very thin, opacity=.5] (0, -2) grid (6.3, 2);
    
    \draw[test={.5}{.5}] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[] (\cpi/2 +.5, 0) circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[test={1}{.5}, blue] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[blue] (\cpi/2 +1, 0) circle (1.25pt);

    \draw[test={2}{.5}, red] (0, 0) -- ++(6.3, 0);
    \filldraw[red] (\cpi/2 +2, 0) circle (1.25pt);
    \draw[shift={(4pt, -3pt)}, test={2}{.5}, green] (0, 0) -- ++(7, 0);

    \draw[fill=white] (\cpi, 0) circle (1.5pt);   

    \path (4, -1.5) node[right] {asp=0.5};
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

